# Getting exception when trying to delete a line from a text file. How can i solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of form1:

```
StreamWriter recentfiles;
string[] lines;
string line = null;
int line_number = 0;
string RecentFiles = "";
```

In the constructor:

```
RecentFiles = @"e:\RecentFiles.txt";
if (!File.Exists(RecentFiles))
{
    recentfiles = new StreamWriter(RecentFiles);
    recentfiles.Close();
}
else
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(RecentFiles);
    items = File
            .ReadLines(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt")
            .Select(line => new ToolStripMenuItem()
            {
              Text = line
            })
            .ToArray();
}
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    if (!File.Exists(items[i].Text))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(RecentFiles))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(RecentFiles))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line_number++;

                    if (line_number == i)
                        continue;

                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the text file RecentFiles for example in the first line I have:

```
d:\test.txt
```

In the second line:

```
e:\test\test.txt
```

What I want to do is that if one of the files in the text file is not exist remove it delete it from the RecentFiles.txt

But I'm getting exception on the line:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(RecentFiles))
```

The process cannot access the file 'e:\RecentFiles.txt' because it is being used by another process

How can i solve it ?

Comment: You're trying to open the file for reading and writing at the same time. That's not going to work.

Comment: in fact it looks like you try to open it a total of 4 times. You already read all the lines into 'lines', so just use that instead of a new reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make it better:

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines(RecentFiles);
List< ToolStripMenuItem > items = new List< ToolStripMenuItem >();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(RecentFiles))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (File.Exists(lines[i])) {
            writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem()
              {
                Text = lines[i]
              });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Garr i tried your solution now. So i marked in my program not to use my own lines and items variables and using your code. But the result is the text file RecentFiles.txt is empty now. In fact it's not realy empty i can move down 3-4 lines the lines are empty. For the test(after did backup) i deleted two text files so they are not exist and when running the program now the RecentFiles.txt is empty with empty lines.

Comment: typo. change line to lines[i], as I will edit the answer

Comment: main difference from yours is items will be a list, not array, but you can easily convert to an array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this does what you need:

```
File.WriteAllLines(RecentFiles,
    File.ReadAllLines(RecentFiles)
        .Where(f => File.Exists(f)));
```